# What is the order of execution In Django Tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, fixtures, django-settings

Here is an example test class:

```py
@decorator_1()
class SimpleTest(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['test_fixture.json']

    def setup(self):        
        x =1
        y=2

    def teardown(self):        
        x =None
        y=None


    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEquals(1,1)

    @decorator_2 
    def test_two(self):
        self.assertEquals(2,2)
```

In what order are each of these pieces executed?:

```
setup
teardown
fixture loading
decorator_1
decorator_2 
test_one
test_2
```

I am trying to find a way to override a settings variable before the fixtures are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To include a whole new file

```
import sys
try:
    if 'test' in sys.argv:        
        from testsettings import *
except ImportError:
    print "something went wrong with the import"
del sys
```

To modify a few settings

```
import sys
try:
    if 'test' in sys.argv:        
        MY_SETTING = 'xxy'
        del MY_SETTING_2
except Exception as e:
    print "something went wrong %s" % e.message
del sys
```

**NOTE:** If you want del a setting you have to do it from the file you are importing into. It can not be in the file you are importing.